# Extract customer ids and their total orders

Tags: python, shell, scripting

I have log files like

```
"01-01-2012 01:13:36 sometext date customerid:1768 orders:3 apples" 
"01-09-2013 01:18:34 sometext date customerid:1567678 orders:4 oranges" 
"08-10-2000 08:08:28 sometext date customerid:156 orders:5 grapes"
```

How do i create a python program which reports customer id and their total number of orders in Python. thanks for the help

Note: i am able to extract customer ids and orders using python builtin functions(startswith,etc) and save in different list, i am stuck at generating a report with customer ids and with their total orders.

Comment: Please explain your difficulties by actually showing the code you wrote and explicitly indicate where in your code you are having difficulty. From what you attempted, where are your errors/issues? If you are getting some kind of output from your current code, show what it currently looks like, and then indicate what it *should* look like.

Comment: @idjaw Mind if i save your comment to my AutoReviewComments bank?

Comment: @leaf sure! Go ahead :)

Comment: @idjaw Thanks. Its the perfect, quick response! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {}
with open('log.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        id_user = [int(s) for s in line.split() if s.isdigit()][0] # this basically means to use the first digit in the line as the user id.
        if not id_user in data:
            data[id_user] = []
        data[id_user].append(line)

for id_user, lines in data.items():
    print(id_user, len(lines))
```

**EDITED** following OP comment :

```
data = {}
with open('log.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        customer_id = [s for s in f.split() if s.find('customerid') != -1][0].split(':')[1]
        if not customer_id in data:
            data[customer_id] = []
        data[customer_id].append(line)

for customer_id, lines in data.items():
    print(customer_id, len(lines))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice and code.how about the logs in the log file starts with a date something like below
"01-01-2012 01:13:36 somedata :Customerid:1234 somedata orders:4 date" please help

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
rex = re.compile("sometext date customer:(\d+) orders;(\d+)")
output = []
for data in logs:
    b = rex.search(data)
    output.append({"customer_id":b.group(1), "orders": b.group(2)})

print output
```

logs is the data from log files (open the file and readlines to read the data from file)

Comment: This will not work, that's because `sometext date` part is only a placeholder here, and will be filled by appropriate value in each line, which naturally should not be same. So you may find a more generic expressions that match the input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice and code.how about the logs in the log file starts with a date something like below
"01-01-2012 01:13:36 somedata :Customerid:1234 somedata orders:4 date" please help